# Regexp notepad ++ busqueda hasta el primer elemento y susitucion modo bucle

Tags: regex, notepad++

estaba usando notepad++ y tenía más o menos una expresión para reemplazar en un documento que es la siguiente

```
<div class="ini">([\d\w\W]+)miFin" />
```

Esta expresión si lo pongo en la búsqueda me encuentra cualquier cadena caracteres entre `<div class="ini">` y `miFin" />`

El problema es que mi documento tiene varios `<div class="ini">` y `miFin" />`
por lo que la búsqueda empieza en el primer `<div class="ini">` y acaba en el último `miFin" />` quería que acabara en el primer `miFin" />` que encuentre.

Por otro lado suponiendo que en el documento tenga varios

```
<div class="cuenta">
```

Quería saber si había alguna expresión para que los reemplazara todos los `<div class="cuenta">` por `<div class="cuenta1">` `<div class="cuenta2">` ... `<div class="cuentaN">`, es decir que vaya iterando.

Comment: Son preguntas totalmente diferentes. Creo que deberías separarla en dos preguntas ya que SO se basa en dar respuestas concretas a preguntas concretas, y esas dos no están relacionadas. Si te parece bien, edita la pregunta y elimina lo del caso de `cuenta`. Crea una nueva pregunta para ese caso y acuérdate de adjuntar un ejemplo del html que intentas tratar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El cuantificador `+` es 'greedy' o 'avaricioso', así que irá acumulando caracteres hasta que no encuentre nada más.

Para tu caso, tendrías que hacerlo 'lazy'/'perezoso', y eso lo puedes hacer poniéndole el símbolo `?` detrás. Así: `+?`

Comentar además que aunque no sea incorrecto, en este en esta character class te sobra el `\d`: `[\d\w\W]`

Estás diciendo que un caracter puede ser dígito o palabra o no palabra. Lo cual quiere decir básicamente "cualquier caracter".

Sobraría el `\d`, ya que el `\W (no palabra)` te lo incluye.

Así pues la regex quedaría así:

```
<div class="ini">([\w\W]+?)miFin" />
```

Comment: Ok gracias, una de las dos preguntas solucionadas.

Comment: No dudes en crear una nueva pregunta para lo otro que necesitas :)